# Getting the value of an input field within a form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me understand why the console log fails to print the value if I wrap the input field in a form field?

HTML:

```
  <form>
      <input id="formEntry" type="text">
      <button id="btn-3">Add Custom Line</button>
  </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
 var addCustomLine = function(){
      var customLine = document.getElementById("formEntry").value;
      console.log(customLine);
 }

 document.getElementById("btn-3").addEventListener ("click", addCustomLine, false);
```

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails if I wrap it in a form"? Are you saying the code works if you omit the `<form>` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By not specifying the button type, it submits the parent form by default. You can prevent this behavior by setting the type explicitly to "button".

```
<button type="button" id="btn-3">Add Custom Line</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `<button>` in a `<form>` will *submit* that form by default, which will cause the page to reloaded and nullify all effects that the event handler had. You can however prevent that behaviour:

```
function addCustomLine(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    …
}
```

You'll want to install that handler on the `submit` event of the form usually, not the `click` event of the button.